# Matlab FFT2 normalization after processing

Tags: matlab, fft, normalization, ifft

I am trying to understand how the MATLAB FFT normalization works.

Lets discuss the following example.

```
%%
sum2D = @(a) sum(reshape(a,1,[]));             % sum elements in 2D matrix

a = [0 0 0; 1 2 1; 1 1 1; 1 1 1; 0 0 0]

f1 = fft2(a)

m = [0 32 0; 0 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 2 0; 0 0 0]

fs = m.*fftshift(f1);
fs = fs./sqrt(numel(fs));

fm = ifft2(fs);
fm = fm.*sqrt(numel(fm))

% imshow(abs(fs))

norm(a(:))^2,norm(fs(:))^2,norm(fm(:))^2

sum2D(abs(a).^2)
sum2D(abs(fs).^2)
sum2D(abs(fm).^2)
sum2D(abs(fp).^2)
```

If the m = 1, the normalization works and the energy is the same in the initial signal, fft and inverse fft. But if I multiply the signal after making fft by some vector m, then I don't know how to normalize this again.

Should the energy change after multiplying with the m, or I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, multiplying the frequencies by matrix `m` changes the energy. You have amplified some frequencies and killed others: this may well make the signal stronger or weaker. As a simple example, suppose `m` had all entries equal to 2: then you double the signal, multiplying its energy by 4. For a general multiplier `m`, the effect on the energy will depend on what the signal is.

If you really want `fm` to have the same energy as `a`, just make it so:

```
fm = fm*norm(a(:))/norm(fm(:));
```

To directly answer "how FFT normalization works": applying `fft2` multiplies the energy by the number of elements of the matrix. The function `ifft2`, being the inverse of `fft2`, divides the energy by the number of elements. So, if you are using `ifft2` after `fft2` and don't care about intermediate results such as `fs`, you don't need to do any division or multiplication by `sqrt(numel(...))`.